# Sklearn: negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I have used sklearn `NearestNeighbors` package to classify a dataset. It worked fine until I tried to use `'distance'` weighting in KNN prediction. I got an error saying that `negative dimensions are not allowed` when I switched from `'uniform'` weights to `'distance'` weights. The `'uniform'` weights worked fine.

The error message is as follows:

```
/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/regression.py:160: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  y_pred[:, j] = num / denom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis.py", line 333, in <module>
    main()
  File "analysis.py", line 330, in main
    ind_test_labels, trainIDs, ind_test_IDs, train_data_original, ind_test_data_original)
  File "analysis.py", line 297, in target1
    outfile = generate_result(X, feature_names, train_label, outfile, trainIDs, train_labels, best_k, train_data_original, ind_test_data_original)
  File "analysis.py", line 130, in generate_result
    predicted_label = regressor.predict(test)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/regression.py", line 144, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 332, in kneighbors
    return_distance=return_distance)
  File "binary_tree.pxi", line 1313, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query (sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.c:10528)
  File "binary_tree.pxi", line 595, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.NeighborsHeap.__init__ (sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.c:4937)
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

I'm confused by the error message. The only thing I can guess is that there is a same instance in both training and testing set so the inverse of its distance would cause a division by zero error. But this is not likely to happen in 6 features.

So can anyone point out where it gets wrong? Or can you point me to a possible direction so I may provide more details?

------update---------------------
I pasted the code snippet that went wrong.
The training X is read and manipulated as follows:

```
train_data = np.loadtext(...)
train_data = preprocessing.scale(train_data);
X_T = train_data.T
X = X_T[[features]].T # features is a tuple that contains columns to be selected for classification
# Then X is passed to generate_result below
#######################################
def generate_result(X, feature_names, train_label, outfile, IDs, labels, k, train_original, ind_test_original):
  """
  Purpose: this function does the analysis and outputs the result to file
  Inputs: training set, names of selected features, training set labels, file writer stream, IDs of training set,
          labels of training set, number of neighbors, original training set, independent test set 
  Returns: file writer stream
  """
  cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(X), 10) # 10-fold cross-validation
  feature_str = ','.join(feature_names)
  outfile.write('Best K = ' + str(k) + '\n')
  outfile.write('10-Fold Cross Validation begins \n')
  numCV = 1 #predicted_GFR_str = array_to_string(predicted_label)
  for traincv, testcv in cv:
    outfile.write('Iteration: ' + str(numCV) + '\n')
    outfile.write(complete_features + ',label' + str(numCV) + ',Catagory' + str(numCV) + '\n')
    train = X[traincv]
    test = X[testcv]
    ### run regression
    regressor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = k, weights = 'distance', p = 1)       

    label_cv_train = train_label[traincv]
    regressor.fit(train, label_cv_train)
    test = X[testcv]
    label_cv_test = train_label[testcv]
    predicted_label = regressor.predict(test)# THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM


    # more code below not pasted
```

Comment: Try googling for "ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed" and you'll see that error cropping up in many different situations involving scikit-learn, scipy.sparse, pandas... To narrow it down we really need to see your actual code. Could you try and post a minimal example that reproduces the error?

Comment: @ruyan, can you reproduce the error on randomly generated data (e.g. with `numpy.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)` or with one of the datasets generator from `sklearn.datasets`)?

Comment: Also which version of scikit-learn are you using? Can you reproduce it on the master branch?

Comment: Finally the line you marked with "THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM" is not causing the traceback as it does not call the `predict` method as reported in the original traceback (and to call `predict` you need to call `fit` first which is not the case in this code snippet either).

Comment: @ogrisel Thanks for your comment. I have updated my code to include the predict method which actually caused the problem. My sklearn version is 0.15.2. And yes, if use 'sklearn.dataset' generator to generate a X1, Y1 for train and X2, Y2 for test, and load them into the KNN regression model, the 'predict' would also cause this error

Comment: Can you post a minimal example using synthetic data? It is not really possible to run the code that you posted without additional code.